# virtuoso rdfs rule set

Tags: virtuoso

I was trying the following example from http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/rdfsparqlrule.html.
Loaded data into the graph:

```
ttlp ('<http://localhost:8890/dataspace> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://rdfs.org/sioc/ns#Space> . 
<http://localhost:8890/dataspace/test2/weblog/test2tWeblog> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://rdfs.org/sioc/types#Weblog> . 
<http://localhost:8890/dataspace/discussion/oWiki-test1Wiki> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://rdfs.org/sioc/types#MessageBoard> . 
<http://localhost:8890/dataspace> <http://rdfs.org/sioc/ns#link> <http://localhost:8890/ods> . 
<http://localhost:8890/dataspace/test2/weblog/test2tWeblog> <http://rdfs.org/sioc/ns#link> <http://localhost:8890/dataspace/test2/weblog/test2tWeblog> . 
<http://localhost:8890/dataspace/discussion/oWiki-test1Wiki> <http://rdfs.org/sioc/ns#link> <http://localhost:8890/dataspace/discussion/oWiki-test1Wiki> .
', '', 'http://localhost:8890/test');
```

Assertions about subclasses and subproperties:

```
ttlp (' @prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> . 
<http://rdfs.org/sioc/ns#Space> rdfs:subClassOf <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#Resource> . 
<http://rdfs.org/sioc/ns#Container> rdfs:subClassOf <http://rdfs.org/sioc/ns#Space> . 
<http://rdfs.org/sioc/ns#Forum> rdfs:subClassOf <http://rdfs.org/sioc/ns#Container> . 
<http://rdfs.org/sioc/types#Weblog> rdfs:subClassOf <http://rdfs.org/sioc/ns#Forum> . 
<http://rdfs.org/sioc/types#MessageBoard> rdfs:subClassOf <http://rdfs.org/sioc/ns#Forum> . 
<http://rdfs.org/sioc/ns#link> rdfs:subPropertyOf <http://rdfs.org/sioc/ns> . ', 
'', 'http://localhost:8890/schema/test');
```

Define the rule:

```
rdfs_rule_set ('http://localhost:8890/schema/property_rules1', 'http://localhost:8890/schema/test');
```

Execute query:

```
define input:inference "http://localhost:8890/schema/property_rules1" 
SELECT ?s FROM <http://localhost:8890/test> 
WHERE {?s <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type>  <http://rdfs.org/sioc/ns#Space> };
```

This gives me only 1 result row - `http://localhost:8890/dataspace`.
While I'm suppose to get 3 rows:

- `http://localhost:8890/dataspace/test2/weblog/test2tWeblog`
- `http://localhost:8890/dataspace/discussion/oWiki-test1Wiki`
- `http://localhost:8890/dataspace`

Can anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here. Does the dba needs to be granted any permission to rdfs_rule_set?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a known issue in some older builds of Virtuoso...

So, can you detail what build of Virtuoso you are using and on what operating system?

( I believe this issue was fixed in Virtuoso Open Source 6.1.4 and Commercial 6.3...)